# Understanding numpy percentile computation

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, ranking, percentile

I understand percentile in the context of test scores with many examples (eg. you SAT score falls in the 99th percentile), but I am not sure I understand percentile in the following context and what is going on. Imagine a model outputs probabilities (on some days we have a lot of new data and outputted probabilities, and some days we don't). Imagine I want to compute the 99th percentile of outputted probabilities. Here are the probabilities for today:

```
a = np.array([0,0.2,0.4,0.7,1])
p = np.percentile(a,99)
print(p)

0.988
```

I don't understand how the 99th percentile is computed in this situation where there are only 5 outputted probabilities. How was the output computed? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear interpolation is applied. You can check consistency yourself:

```
a = np.array([0,0.2,0.4,0.7,1])

np.sort(a)  # array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.7,  1. ])

np.percentile(a, 75)   # 0.70
np.percentile(a, 100)  # 1.0
np.percentile(a, 99)   # 0.988

0.70 + (1.0 - 0.70) * (99 - 75) / (100 - 75)  # 0.988
```

The documentation also [specifies `'linear'` as the default](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

> `numpy.percentile(a, q, axis=None, out=None, overwrite_input=False, interpolation='linear', keepdims=False)`
>
> **'linear'**: `i + (j - i) * fraction`, where `fraction` is the fractional part of the index surrounded by `i` and `j`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I always have done percentiles in the context of large datasets, but this is very clear and reasonable.